# How to increase the volume gain when viewing online flash video?

Tags: flash

When watching online Flash videos on Youtube or DailyMotion sometimes the videos are recorded at low volume.

The thing is that, I have a HP Notebook with good enough audio volume, but when I watch these "low volume" videos the sound level is really low, even when I have the volume at 100%.

So I am looking for a way to increase the volume gain (like VLC player where you can increase it to 200%), BUT while watching it live on YouTube... that is, I don't want to download the video on my PC.

Is there a software that can do that? Maybe an advanced flash video player that integrates to browser? or some other software to increase the volume gain overall on my laptop?

My Specs:

HP Pavilion Notebook, Audio: IDT High Definition Audio CODEC (integrated), Vista 64-bit, 4 GB RAM, etc.

Answer (score 5):

There is a better way...
**ON WINDOWS 7 64BIT**

***Use Sound Enhancements***

1. Click on the system tray arrow and right-click the speaker icon, select Playback devices from the drop down list.
2. Double-click your default speakers (not sure? start a track and see if green bars appear)
3. Go to the tab Enhancements and check the option Loudness Equalization
4. Go to the tab Enhancements and check the option Loudness Equalization

There you go...

Comment: Actually a nice tip, but I'm not sure about the accuracy on this being specific to Windows 7 64 bit.

Answer (score 0):

you don't have to download to play in vlc just highlight the link like http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FHtvDA0W34I and drag it to an open vlc player and it works. hope this helps

Comment: That doesn't seem to work for me (Windows 7, IE9, VLC 2.0.3).