# Is it possible to increase the audio volume on a streamed video?

Tags: audio, video, streaming

Is it possible to increase the audio volume on a streamed video?

Playback from files is fine, I am always able to increase past 100% using VLC but playback from  streamed source, such as iPlayer, is often very low.

Specifically I am looking for solutions applicable to a MacBook Pro but any info for any system would be interesting and may help me work towards a solution.

I have seen a few question asked before but no solutions:
[How to increase the volume gain when viewing online flash video?](https://superuser.com/questions/239713/how-to-increase-the-volume-gain-when-viewing-online-flash-video)

To clarify, I am looking for a solution that would only require changes to the configuration of the system, a software solution rather than adding new hardware. The changes should increase the volume on streaming content, rather than downloading and changing.

In essence, I suppose, i am asking: Is it possible to make (configuration) changes to a MacBook Pro to increase the maximum volume. Please let me know if you think i should open a new question instead (or move to a more appropriate Stack)

Comment: you can use the FFMpeg to boost the volume.
see the below link for your solution: [https://superuser.com/questions/323119/how-can-i-normalize-audio-using-ffmpeg](https://superuser.com/questions/323119/how-can-i-normalize-audio-using-ffmpeg)

Answer (score 1):

You should try [Boom](http://www.globaldelight.com/boom/). Increases the volume of the entire system (not just the video)

Comment: Thanks for suggesting Boom Bala. It would solve the problem by increasing the whole systems volume but I am only really hoping to increase the volume of streamed content as it is being streamed. I am hoping to get a suggestion about altering the codec or a setting somewhere within the OS or browser. (but it is looking like Boom is going to be the only solution.

Answer (score 0):

1. Download and re-encode the videos at a higher volume level.
     (With the right plugins/extension in firefox you can download youtube videos)
2. Get an amplifier or run it through a stereo system and crank the volume up.
    (You can get stereo amplifier with incredible gain)(till your speakers give out)